# Problems with planning components visualizer

Tags: arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I ran the arm planning wizard in easy mode and it generates a set of config and launch files for my arm perfectly fine.

Now I tried the planning components visualizer. The problem is, when I interact with my model, it looks like the planning visualizer cannot find IK solution for any attempted positioning of the end effector except up and down sometimes.

The pr2 example in the tutorial works fine.
I tried some other limits in the joints, but nothing changed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31072/problems-with-planning-components-visualizer/) by [jens](https://answers.ros.org/users/1933/jens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-04-03**:
Is there any error message or pictures to say more clear? Thank you~

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-04-03**:
Do you have enabled the joint control? Must be within a context menu in the visualizer. Does it work fine if you directly turn your joints from a good position instead of moving the end effector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah that works.
As  I selected Joint Control in the visualizer I could move every Joint in every position that I wanted. But it didn't work when I moved the end effector. Is it enough for the planning to work only with Joint Control?
P.S. It looked like a scale problem. The same model with scale x10 works better.

---

Originally posted by [jens](https://answers.ros.org/users/1933/jens/) with karma: 16 on 2012-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0